Tensorflow Import error on another machine
Everything works on my home PC. But when I transferred the project with environment to the server, errors began to occur with Tensorflow:
C:\Users\Administrator>cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\Scripts

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\Scripts>activate.bat

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\Scripts>python
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import tf2 as _tf2
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tf2.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.platform import _pywrap_tf2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tf2: The specified module could not be found.

activate.bat: https://pastebin.com/esKmGvw2
Another error with another Python version:
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\Scripts>activate.bat

(venv) C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\Scripts>python
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
>>> import tensorflow
2024-04-22 23:14:49.562778: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2 import __internal__
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import autograph
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\autograph\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.core.ag_ctx import control_status_ctx # line: 34
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\core\ag_ctx.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils import ag_logging
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\utils\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils.context_managers import control_dependency_on_returns
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\utils\context_managers.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyProject\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 5906, in <module>
    ) -> Optional[Callable[[Any], message.Message]]:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 243, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 316, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem(self, parameters)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 433, in Optional
    return Union[arg, type(None)]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 243, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 316, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem(self, parameters)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 421, in Union
    parameters = _remove_dups_flatten(parameters)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\typing.py", line 215, in _remove_dups_flatten
    all_params = set(params)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'


Home PC: Windows 11 x64, Python 3.9.13
Server: Windows Server 2022 21H2, Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable x64 installed.
TF version: 2.16.1 (maximum supported version with latest keras)


Hi @D .Stark, It seems there is issue with the installed TensorFlow. Could you please try again by uninstalling the TensorFlow from your server and install it back and also try installing the latest or Python version atleast 3.10. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.

I got the same error and all I did was to shift from my python 3.9.0 to python 3.10.11 and it worked!

The answer from D .Stark says that 3.9.13 worked for them, is there a need to change minor part in major.minor.patch scheme? This might break something, as the versions in which minor changes are not guarantied to be backwards-compatible.

The banal installation of a similar version of Python on the server helped me (3.9.13 instead of 3.9.0)
